# Open a dummy X in another X session

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, display

How could I open a dummy X session created with the **xserver-xorg-video-dummy** in another X session, say that one which created display :0?

The session is created with the command:

```
$ sudo X :1 -config dummy-1024x768.conf
```

Contents of dummy-1024x768.conf file:

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor0"
  HorizSync 28.0-80.0
  VertRefresh 48.0-75.0
  Modeline "1024x768_60.00" 64.11 1024 1080 1184 1344 768 769 772 795 -HSync +Vsync
EndSection

Section "Device"
  Identifier "Card0"
  Driver "dummy"
  VideoRam 32000
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  DefaultDepth 24
  Identifier "Screen0"
  Device "Card0"
  Monitor "Monitor0"
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1024x768_60.00"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

And a program is started there with:

```
$ DISPLAY=:1 x-session-manager
```

I know that later I can use VNC to access it, with the commands:

```
$ x11vnc -rfbport 0 -viewonly -forever -nolookup -nopw -quiet -unixsock ~/vncsock1 -display :1
$ ssvncviewer -encodings Raw -compresslevel 1 -quality 9 -nojpeg -nocursorshape unix=~/vncsock1
```

But it's too slow, even with sockets.

Is there another method to open such multiple, custom, dummy X sessions in a faster way?

Comment: how about **not** making it dummy? Make it a real X session with real graphics

Comment: @user253751 You mean by only changing: driver "dummy" to: driver "radeon" for example? With that I lost my already logged in X session, or there are other steps involved? Seems a good approach but it looks like i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Do you know about virtual terminals?

Comment: @user253751 Ohhh you're right! Executed from other vt and didn't lose my session =D Facing other problems now: started an application in the new X but the vnc session, from the other X, only show me a black screen.

Comment: @user253751 I didn't notice much difference using a real driver, guess the slowness is with the vnc client side. Must be another way to access the new X session inside the other one, without vnc.